# combining 2 queries in one Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

First SQL query :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT
        rec_business.personal_id,
        rec_business.id AS id,
        rec_personal.l_name AS last_name,
        rec_personal.f_name AS first_name,
        rec_personal.m_name AS middle_name,
        rec_business.bus_name AS bus_name,
        rec_business.reg_type AS reg_type,
        rec_business_type.name AS buss_type,
        rec_business.address AS address,
        rec_business.reg_date AS reg_date,
        rec_business.expire_date AS exp_date
    FROM
        rec_business
        INNER JOIN rec_personal ON rec_business.personal_id = rec_personal.id 
        INNER JOIN rec_business_type ON rec_business_type.id = rec_business.bus_nature
    WHERE rec_business.expire_date > NOW()
) t
```

Second SQL query :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT
        rec_business.personal_id,
        rec_business.id AS id,
        rec_personal.l_name AS last_name,
        rec_personal.f_name AS first_name,
        rec_personal.m_name AS middle_name,
        rec_business.bus_name AS bus_name,
        rec_business.reg_type AS reg_type,
        rec_business_type.name AS buss_type,
        rec_business.address AS address,
        rec_business.reg_date AS reg_date,
        rec_business.expire_date AS exp_date
    FROM
        rec_business
        INNER JOIN rec_personal ON rec_business.personal_id = rec_personal.id
        INNER JOIN rec_business_type ON rec_business_type.id = rec_business.bus_nature
    WHERE rec_business.expire_date <= NOW()
) t
```

How to combine these two queries in one

Comment: 2 fields or 2 rows?

Comment: 2 fields .......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not tested but something like....

```
SELECT 
COUNT(CASE WHEN rec_business.expire_date > NOW() THEN 1 END) AS NotExpired,
COUNT(CASE WHEN rec_business.expire_date <= NOW() THEN 1 END) AS Expired,
COUNT(1) As TotalCount
FROM rec_business
    INNER JOIN rec_personal
        ON rec_business.personal_id = rec_personal.id
    INNER JOIN rec_business_type
        ON rec_business_type.id = rec_business.bus_nature
```

Comment: sir can i ask for the total of two?

Answer (score 0):

`sum()` is the right function for what you intend instead of `count()` :

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN rcb.expire_date > NOW() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NotExpired,
       SUM(CASE WHEN rcb.expire_date <= NOW() THEN 1 END) AS Expired,
       COUNT(1) As TotalCount
FROM rec_business rcb INNER JOIN 
     rec_personal rcp
     ON rcb.personal_id = rcp.id INNER JOIN 
     rec_business_type rbt
     ON rbt.id = rcb.bus_nature;
```